# How do I add the __Secure prefix in this .htaccess line?

Tags: .htaccess, cookie

Sorry, I'm not an Apache expert.

I need to add the `__Secure` prefix to this htaccess line:

```
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"
```

is this possible? How?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Sorry, I meant Apache because of the usage of htaccess files

Answer (score 1):

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

Does this give you the information you need:

https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/

> **Implementation Procedure in Apache**
>
> - Ensure you have `mod_headers.so` enabled in Apache HTTP server
> - Add following entry in `httpd.conf`:
>
>   ```
>   Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
>   ```
> - Restart Apache HTTP server to test

**UPDATE 2022-12-21 @ 20:58GMT**

Guidance on [this](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-validate-set-cookie-header/) site indicates the format to be `Set-Cookie: __Secure-ID=123; Secure; Domain=example.com; HttpOnly`

Also following [MDN syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#syntax), from your example, I would expect you need:

```
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "__Secure-$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"
```

You might also want to add in `; HttpOnly`strong text too at the end.

```
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "__Secure-$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure; HttpOnly"
```

Comment: This does not add the __Secure prefix

Comment: [This](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-validate-set-cookie-header/) site is probably useful: `Set-Cookie: __Secure-ID=123; Secure; Domain=example.com; HttpOnly`, as is the [MDN syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#syntax), so in your example, I would expect you need `Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "__Secure-$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"` - You might also want to add in `; HttpOnly` too at the end.